# Does Spinnaker's rosco use HashiCorp's packer or is it another tool?

Tags: cicd

I am confused. Does Spinnaker use HashiCorp's Packer for baking or is it another tool? The reason for asking this that a folder called packer resides in the github repo of rosco https://github.com/spinnaker/rosco/blob/master/rosco-web/config/packer/docker.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [spinnaker own documentation](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/architecture/)

> Rosco is the bakery. It is used to produce machine images (e.g. GCE
>   images, AWS AMIs, Azure VM images). It presently wraps [packer](https://www.packer.io/), but
>   will shortly be expanded to support additional mechanisms for
>   producing images.

So yes, rosco uses HashiCorp's packer.

The main reason to use packer is that you just need to change the provider used to create a docker image or an AWS ami or an Azure image and keep your building step identical.